# Ajax multiple button click

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I have this site that show users who i can follow or not. its working without ajax but it get to reload on every button click.

I added ajax but it only stores the first following_id of the user displayed first into the database and nothing more. and its not right at all. having a long list of users and only one gets inserted into the database.

However, if i click on about 2 or more users to follow it inserts 2 or more rows of 1 following_id instead of 2 or more rows of different following_id been clicked.

Thanks in advance.

**my ajax script**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".followUser").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $('#userAction').serialize();
            var action = 'instant_follow.php';
     
            $.post(action, form, function(data){
              //result goes here...
            });
        });

        $('button#followResult').live('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $button = $(this);
            if($button.hasClass('unfollow')){          
              $button.removeClass('unfollow');
              $button.text('follow');
              $button.addClass('follow');
            } else {
              $button.addClass('unfollow');
              $button.text('unfollow');
            }
        });
    });
```

***my php select form same page with my ajax script***

```
$user = "1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM site_users AS s LEFT JOIN site_follows AS f ON (f.following_id = s.user_id AND f.follower_id = ?) WHERE s.user_id != ? AND f.follow_id IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $user, $user);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '
                <form id="userAction" action="" method="post">
                    <p>'.$row["username"].'</p>
                    <button class="followUser" id="followResult">follow</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="following_id" value="'.$row["user_id"].'">
                </form>
            ';
        }
    } else {
        echo "no user found...";
    }
```

**My php insert query on a different page**

```
//user id which is 1
$user = "1";
$following_id = $_POST["following_id"];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO site_follows (following_id, follower_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $following_id, $user);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
```

Comment: what you actually want??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem is simply because you have given same id to all your form so whichever button you will clicked only first form will get submitted .Instead get value of submit button using `$(this).closest("form").serialize()` so this will get only form where button has been clicked .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".followUser", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $button = $(this);
    var form = $(this).closest("form").serialize();//get closest form where button is 
    console.log(form)
    var action = 'instant_follow.php';
    //your ajax
    if ($button.hasClass('unfollow')) {
      $button.addClass('follow').removeClass('unfollow');
      $button.text('follow');
    } else {
      $button.addClass('unfollow').removeClass('follow');
      $button.text('unfollow');
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <p>Abc</p>
  <button class="followUser" id="followResult">follow</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="following_id" value="1">
</form>
<form action="" method="post">
  <p>Xyz</p>
  <button class="followUser" id="followResult">follow</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="following_id" value="2">
</form>
```